# How to prompt user to accept website certificate using javascript

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes

Mainly the scenario is that there are two websites. The two website implements single sign-on. So if you login to the first website, you are considered logged on as well on the other. The problem is that the first website tries to get information such as XML from the second website; however, some users do not go to the second website in order to be automatically prompted by their browsers to accept/deny the certificate for that website.

Is there a way through javascript that if the user goes to the specific page in the first website, it will check if their browser has the certificate from the second website. If not, it will prompt the user to install the certificate from the second website in order for the contents of the page in the first website to fully load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX and self-signed certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422767/ajax-and-self-signed-certificate) -- have you considered opening an iframe to the site with a self-signed cert? (I'm not sure if that will show the prompt or not, but doing a redirect certainly will.) Also, have you considered just getting a certificate signed by a trusted CA instead?

Comment: Yes very similar. The certificate is self-signed. The answer in that question could be my last resort. Still trying to find a better way for it. The two website are only within the intranet of the company.